# Xamarin.Forms Listview Context Actions For Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin.Forms app on Android, context actions for listview highlights the selected cell in white after longpress and changes the navigation bar so that it includes the options. Isn't the default behavior for Android context menu items to appear as a pop-up? As far as I know, showing context actions on the navbar is usually applicable when we can do a multi-select. Or even if it is shown for a single selection, there is usually a check mark next to that row rather than having the row highlighted in white. Does anyone know why Xamarin.Forms  implemented this in Android as such? Is there an example of such a use case in any Android app? Here is a screenshot from their guide:

[image]

And finally, how can it be customised for it to follow the default Android behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on Android [`ContextActions`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#Context_Actions) are implemented through items in the navigation bar. If you want a different behavior, you would have to implement it yourself or use another control. Additionally, `ContextActions` are for a single cell item only - no multi select.

To find out the real implementation have a look in the [source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms).

If you don't want a white background you have to adapt the styles. Either with `Xamarin.Forms` or natively. I use native styles here.